# How do I change the resolution/capabilities of a v4l2loopback device on the fly?

Tags: ffmpeg, v4l2loopback

I'm trying to switch from one advertised resolution/framerate to a different one on the fly, preferably while other applications are consuming the v4l2loopback feed. As an example, I feed a 1920x1080 black screen video into `/dev/video2`, and then open it in `vlc`. This works fine:

```
$ ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s=1920x1080:r=25/1 -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -f v4l2 /dev/video2
```

```
$ ffmpeg -f v4l2 -list_formats all -i /dev/video2
ffmpeg version n4.3.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.1.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --disable-debug --disable-static --disable-stripping --enable-avisynth --enable-fontconfig --enable-gmp --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdrm --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgsm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libjack --enable-libmfx --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librav1e --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxcb --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-omx --enable-shared --enable-version3
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x55864f9b06c0] Raw       :     yuv420p :     Planar YUV 4:2:0 : 1920x1080
/dev/video2: Immediate exit requested
```

However, killing the old feed and then streaming a different resolution into the device does not change the advertised capabilities, and just scrambles the screen in vlc.

```
$ ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s=1280x800:r=25/1 -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -f v4l2 /dev/video2

# The list_formats options are still the same (only 1920x1080)
# vlc shows a green instead of a black screen
```

Is it possible to change this on the fly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as long as the device is opened, it's resolution (and format) are fixed.

so the answer to your question is: no, you can't change these settings on the fly.

(unless you quit all consumers (in your case: VLC) before starting the new `ffmpeg`; but that's not what i would call "on the fly")

this is a limitation of the V4L2 API, where you cannot signal a resolution/format change to any attached application.

there also seems to be an issue with `ffmpeg`, which should either

- adjust the output frame-size if it cannot change it
- or refuse to run

(it could also be a bug in the `v4l2loopback` module (not properly reporting back that the framesize didn't change), but with GStreamer it seems to work as expected, so I'm not sure about it)